# Web based app to work with second screen

Tags: browser, web, architecture, frameworks

I want to make a two-screen application: one screen for presenting media content in full screen mode (for simplicity let's say media is simple pictures that are stored on server) and another screen is for controlling the presentation (choosing picture from library).
Is it possible to make such app on web based on 2 browser tabs?
What techs, frameworks can I use for this?
What is the simplest example of such architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js + Express + [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is most easy and fast stack I can think of. If you want those authenticated I'd also suggest using passport.js. If you want to use HTML5 cutting edge you may just use [cross window messaging](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage) instead of socket.io. Of course this stack is for you if you already know or would like to learn javascript. As for frontend you can use whatever you want but I reccomend Angular.js.